# Julia: Visualization of a categorical data on a grid

Tags: plot, julia, heatmap, categorical-data

Sometimes it is needed to draw categorical values on a regular grid to show how they cover a certain area. In principle, the plot() function is a good fit for this, but there is a problem that is needed to adjust the size of the icons each time to create the illusion of a solid cover. When changing the coverage of the image, the old size becomes irrelevant and is needed to adjust it again. Is there a technique to adjust this size automatically?

```
using Plots
using CategoricalArrays
a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
c = CategoricalArray(["X", "X", "Y", "Z", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Y", "Z"])
plot(a, b, group = c, seriestype = :scatter, aspect_ratio = 1, markersize=90, 
markershape=:square, markerstrokewidth=0.0, xlim = (0.5, 3.5), ylim = (0.5, 3.5))
```

The result is good in everything, except that each time you need to adjust the size of the cells so that there are no overlapping areas or gaps:

[image]

As an alternative, I considered heatmap(), but it works quite strangely with categorical data, setting them some kind of scale of its own with a continuous gradation of values. I haven't come across any examples where using heatmap() would get a map with a beautiful legend like plot(), so I'm not sure that using heatmap() is the right way here.

```
a = b = [1, 2, 3]
c = CategoricalArray(["X" "X" "Y"; "Z" "Y" "Y"; "Z" "Y" "Z"])
heatmap(a, b, c)
```

[image]

Maybe there is still some way to automatically set the size of the cells of plot()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various ways to create such a plot within Plots.jl. Perhaps the most obvious interpretation of what you want is [shapes](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/input_data/#Shapes). For that approach, you also need to understand [how to group unconnected data within the same groups](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/input_data/#Unconnected-Data-within-same-groups). A solution based on shapes could look like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
c = CategoricalArray(["X", "X", "Y", "Z", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Y", "Z"])

groups = Dict(cat => NTuple{2,Int}[] for cat in levels(c))
for (ca, cb, cat) in zip(a,b,c)
    push!(groups[cat], (ca,cb))
end

w = 1
shapes = map(collect(groups)) do (cat, vals)
    cat => mapreduce(vcat, vals) do (ca, cb)
        [ca cb] .+ [-.5 -.5; .5 -.5; .5 .5; -.5 .5; -.5 -.5; NaN NaN]*w
    end
end

p = plot(aspect_ratio=1)
for (cat, s) in sort(shapes;by=x->x[1])
    plot!(s[:,1], s[:,2], label=cat, seriestype=:shape, linewidth=0)
end
```

[image]

Most of the code is simply moving the data around so we get a Vector of Pairs from the categorical value to a matrix specifying all of the vertices, like this for "X":

```
"X" =>
12×2 Matrix{Float64}:
   0.5    0.5
   1.5    0.5
   1.5    1.5
   0.5    1.5
   0.5    0.5
 NaN    NaN
   1.5    0.5
   2.5    0.5
   2.5    1.5
   1.5    1.5
   1.5    0.5
 NaN    NaN
```

A perhaps slightly simpler solution would be to "trick" Plots to display what we want using a heatmap, like this:

```
a = b = [1, 2, 3]
c = CategoricalArray(["X" "X" "Y"; "Z" "Y" "Y"; "Z" "Y" "Z"])
pal = palette(:default)
p = plot(aspect_ratio=1, size=(400,400))
heatmap!(a,b,c, c=pal, colorbar=false, clims=(1,length(pal)))
for cat in sort(collect(Set(c)))
    plot!(
        [], [], seriestype=:shape,
        label=cat, color=pal[levelcode(cat)]
    )
end
```

[image]